# is there a way to pull urls from an xml file in java and delete those urls?

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to write a simple program that deletes files from a server. I have the file reading the xml already but it does not pull the urls from the delete file the program compiles with no errors but I feel I am missing something that will pull urls from the xml. Here is what I have so far. I know its probably something really easy but I have been stuck on it for awhile.

```
import folder.AvailableBuilds;
import java.io.File;

public class Cleaner {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("xtf.xml");


    JAXBContext configContext;
    try {
        configContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("path");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = configContext.createUnmarshaller();
        AvailableBuilds theBuilds = (AvailableBuilds) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
   for (AvailableBuilds.BuildGroup group: theBuilds.getBuildGroup()) {
       System.out.println("" + group.getType());

   }
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] x;
    if(file.isDirectory()){
        x = file.list();
        for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            File files = new File("xtf.xml");
            files.delete();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AvailableBuilds>
    <BuildGroup>
        <Type>working</Type>
        <Build>
        </Build>
        <Build>
            <VersionTag>wc-853</VersionTag>
            <DateBuilt>2017-08-24T20:50:55Z</DateBuilt>
            <ExecutableURL>http://example.com/ServerApps/Java/Crossbow/trunk/wc-853/Crossbow_wc-853.zip</ExecutableURL>
            <SupportURL>http://example.com/ServerApps/Java/Crossbow/trunk/wc-853/Crossbow_wc-853_etc.zip</SupportURL>
            <NotesURL>http://example.com/ServerApps/Java/Crossbow/trunk/wc-853/Crossbow_wc-853_notes.txt</NotesURL>
        </Build>
```

Comment: I don't see how your XML is related to your paths, and why are you deleting your XML file?

Comment: Im not trying to delete my xml file I need to parse the file and look at all the urls and delete those urls from the server and update the xml file.

Comment: can you show an example of your xml file  and where those urls are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to separate 2 things:

- getting a list of paths to be deleted
- delete files ( and directories? ) under that path

I would write 2 different methods for that.

Currently I don't understand how you're getting the paths from XML, but you're close to deleting files. Except for the

```
File files = new File("xtf.xml");
files.delete();
```

Which actually delete the XML file itself.

Knowing that I don't know you're XML file format and how you're going to parse it, let's assume it is going to return a list of paths.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> filePaths = getFilePathsFromXML( "xtf.xml" );

    for ( String path : filePaths ) {
        deleteRecursively( path );
    }
}

/**
 * Deletes a file or folder. If a given path is a folder then deletes all files and folders recursively first
 *
 * @param String path - path of a file or directory
**/
static void deleteRecursively( String path ) {
    File file = new File( path );
    if ( file.isDirectory() ) {
        for ( String subPath : file.list() ) {
            deleteRecursively( subPath );
        }
    }
    try {
        file.delete();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Gets a list of file pats from an XML file.
 *
 * @param String fileName - the XML file name for reading
**/
static List<String> getFilePathsFromXML( String fileName ) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    // figure out how to read paths from file
    return result;
}
```